# IDE подсвечивает красным после подключения Lombok

Tags: android, android-studio, компиляция, настройки, lombok

Пишет включить annotation processing в настройках раздела Compiler, но в данном проекте вкладка Compiller не разворачивается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в Gradle добавлено

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
    ...
}
```

Gradle version 4.4
Android plugin version 3.1.4
Build tools 28.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Обновил все зависимости до самых последних версий, а также поставил максимальную версию compileSdkVersion, и все заработало.